# Dovecot issuing LetsEncrypt certificate, openssl / node tls fail to verify

Tags: ssl, dovecot, node.js, lets-encrypt

**EDIT** running `openssl s_client -connect mail.mydomain.com:993 -showcerts -CAfile identtrustroot.pem` works. So that suggests that node tls doesn't have any knowledge of that root, surely that can't be?

I've got a dovecot instance issuing a LetsEncrypt cert for mail.mydomain.com. Thunderbird doens't complain, webmail doesn't complain, but both openssl s_client and nodejs tls do.

Example:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mail.mydomain.com:993 -showcerts

depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=mail.domain.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#
# Removed for brevity
#
ZlmxXZ8eRkcfhlu6Sw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#
# Removed for brevity
#
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/CN=mail.domain.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3176 bytes and written 334 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
```

My doveot config simply points to the Cerbot generated fullchain.pem and privkey.pem.

When using nodejs tls, I get a similar problem:

```
[connection] Error: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
{ Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1108:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:638:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:468:38) code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN', source: 'socket' }
[connection] Closed
```

The certs CN is the same as the host, mail.domain.com, but I can only assume I'm eiter missing a cert or dovecot is in some way incorrectly configured. Has anyone come across this before or got any suggestions?

Comment: Sure it can be https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4175

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my machine (Debian Jessie).  I've had an issue with an older version of the `certbot` client, on an older version of Debian, using Courier - the fullchain.pem certificate wasn't created automatically, I had to `cat` several certs together to generate it each time I updated.

Output of your same sslclient command followed by output of `doveconf -n` from one working machine:

```
ivan@darkstar ~ $ openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:993 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=example.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFVTCCBD2gAwIBAgISA+jVgnfoK82K032B7XyPIuO2MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
** snip **
idWK19DrVDGbqBItrFBkh9FFbaJDt7P7UUcUPtZW1JS8exsMYoz3peSw7unl+FC6
bVoetZqKD86UdI1nRhfsx5cTtY5IoGMdQg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEkjCCA3qgAwIBAgIQCgFBQgAAAVOFc2oLheynCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
** snip **
KOqkqm57TH2H3eDJAkSnh6/DNFu0Qg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/CN=example.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3237 bytes and written 463 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: F533DE0F3B74AA229A9B856A81B36D7B5E537AEDB1A1A70196582BA3734ED361
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 2D16BBC4E5EF3367E448522AB16E8C34C572D0224669FFC9AEECCC6FD2928022E498E761323346D969101B9261825E22
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 02 cb be 44 b3 35 da fc-b9 f1 7f 6f 90 4f 97 9c   ...D.5.....o.O..
    0010 - a8 26 22 8c bb c4 cd e7-f2 94 39 35 27 19 91 b3   .&".......95'...
    0020 - 6b 19 b7 cd 89 55 53 78-c6 ba ee 56 36 42 a5 23   k....USx...V6B.#
    0030 - b0 43 1e a2 be 65 a8 be-fe 4b a1 68 cb f2 31 b5   .C...e...K.h..1.
    0040 - 0f ee 84 e1 d1 b3 e0 9a-c8 5c d1 a3 0f 6b ef c1   .........\...k..
    0050 - 13 c8 2c 1c 7a 43 a5 76-04 a0 d9 5c cf 8e ce a6   ..,.zC.v...\....
    0060 - 26 87 7e d0 0d fd 84 eb-0b 7c 89 7c bf b7 33 94   &.~......|.|..3.
    0070 - d4 1e be d1 07 f2 2c 59-9b b0 b9 4b 73 66 27 63   ......,Y...Ksf'c
    0080 - 21 a0 e9 88 bf d8 5e 47-e0 3d c1 df fc 60 63 c0   !.....^G.=...`c.
    0090 - 1c 67 5e 50 b5 1b 5e 4b-ba 1f 96 4d cc f8 43 a3   .g^P..^K...M..C.

    Start Time: 1506208904
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
```

And the `doveconf -n` output:

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.9.36-x86_64-linode85 x86_64 Debian 8.8 ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_after = /etc/dovecot/sieve-after
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@%d
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
```

Comment: As expected, our config is near identical. I get the same output as you if I specify the CAfile on the openssl command. To be clear, your fullchain is the generated one, and as such only contains 2 certs? I presume yours is working without the CAfile argument because the IdentTrust cert is already in the directory openssl checks for CA root certs.

Comment: Debian has node patched to be integrated in the system trust store.

Comment: @JoeBrailsford - Yes, I've gone through and checked and my fullchain.pem is generated by the certbot script.  I can only assume that it is simply the chain.pem and cert.pem put together.  I'm using certbot v 0.10.2-1~bpo8+1 from the debian jessie repos.  The client I checked from is a Mint 18 serena desktop

Comment: @eckes Indeed the issue is with hard coded ca certs in Node. Another day goes by, another day I question why people use Node...